# java, selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

This is the snapshot of Login popup :
[image]

I'm newbie in Selenium webdriver. I wrote this code to figure out navigate commands but once the browser opens, there is a login popup that is displayed. I tried to close it using classname or xpath but timeout exception occurs.

Do I need to use explicit wait in this case? Could you help me to figure out what the problem is?

```
public class TestNavigateCommands {
WebDriver driver;
public void invokeBrowser(){
    try {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/himaja/Documents/chromedriver");
        ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("start-fullscreen");
        driver=new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        navigateCommands();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void navigateCommands(){
    try {
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.flipkart.com/");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.findElement(By.className("2AkmmA _29YdH8")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='_2AkmmA _29YdH8']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[starts-with(text(),'Applicances')]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Microwave Ovens')]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.navigate().back();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.navigate().forward();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestNavigateCommands test1= new TestNavigateCommands();
    test1.invokeBrowser();

}
```

}

Exception :

> [43.366][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 37.150 
>   [43.373][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.007
>   org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout

Comment: Hi Himaja :) What do you mean by "didn't work"? Does nothing happen? Do you get an exception? Does a gif of a dog pop up on the screen and laugh at you?

Comment: There is timeout exception that I'm getting. The popup is not closed and the other functions are not getting executed.

Comment: can you add the timeout exception to your question? That likely has some valuable debugging information in it.

Comment: @Himaja, Please update your chromedriver version and try again

Comment: Can you update the Question with the full error stack trace and the line at which you see the exception?

Comment: @Himaja is there more to that timeout exception? Usually it'll tell you what it's trying to do when timing out. This information would help narrow down the answers so they aren't as likely to be guesses. The two answers posted are guessing that the popup just hasn't opened when you try to click it, or the element is not visible yet. You could test this theory without trying those solutions by making your sleep 10 seconds or so, or step through the code and only continue when you clearly see the element. My guess is there is another problem though.

Comment: I was getting timeout exception because of driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code it may help:

```
public class TestNavigateCommands {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            try {                
                  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/himaja/Documents/chromedriver");
                  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                  WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,50 );

                  driver.manage().window().maximize();

                  driver.navigate().to("https://www.flipkart.com/");          
                  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'YdH8')]")).click();   


                  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Appliances']//span"))));
                  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Appliances']//span")).click();         

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
        }   
    }
```

Comment: I tried this code and it helped. The page took so long to load and it finally worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestNavigateCommands {
WebDriver driver;

public void invokeBrowser() {
    try {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/himaja/Documents/chromedriver");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("start-fullscreen");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        navigateCommands();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void navigateCommands() {
    try {
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.flipkart.com/");          
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='_3Njdz7']//button[@class='_2AkmmA _29YdH8']")).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Appliances']//span"))));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Appliances']//span")).click();         
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.navigate().back();
        driver.navigate().forward();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please format your code correctly, and add some context for the answer (ie, briefly explain how your code fixes the problem)?

Comment: can you use this code and try it out. Let me know if you are still getting the same issue.

Comment: I'm still having the same issue. Same exception.

Comment: @Himaja: I have updated my answer. please check it out. In this, I changed the page timeout to 60 sec and  few changes in navigateCommands()

Comment: I tried your answer but I'm still having the same timeout issue. I tried checking the code with both chrome and firefox. Is there anyway to disable popup by clicking on anywhere on the page?

Comment: I'm getting exception because of driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);